# How to correct my current code of moving the sprite completely offscreen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm currently trying to script my `gameobject/sprite` in `Unity` to move completely offscreen then be destroyed. But as of now with my current code, the sprite does not move offscreen fully.

Here's my current code:

```
void MoveObstacle()
{
    this.transform.position -= new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, speed * Time.deltaTime, this.transform.position.z);

}

void CheckIfOffscreen()
{
    Vector3 spriteSize = this.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().bounds.size;
    Debug.Log(spriteSize);

    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position);

    if(screenPos.y < 0 - spriteSize.y/2)
    {
        this.DestroyObstacle();
    }
}

void DestroyObstacle()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't make my sprite move completely offscreen before the sprite gets destroyed. It disappears when half of the sprite is offscreen and that's not the behavior I want.

I know I'm just missing something or using the `spriteSize` incorrectly. Anyone know how to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: `spriteSize.y/2` is bang in the middle of the sprite so maybe just `spriteSize.y` without dividing by 2.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I have tried that also. It still disappears halfway through. I think I may be using the bounds.size incorrectly with the screen coordinates

Comment: I see, `GetComponentInChildren` i think should be just `GetComponent`. But i still would get rid of the divide by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I believe this line:

```
this.transform.position -= new Vector3(this.transform.position.x, speed * Time.deltaTime, this.transform.position.z);
```

Should be:

```
this.transform.position -= new Vector3(0, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

And to fix your problem, try this:

```
Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.transform.position + spriteSize);

if(screenPos.y < 0)
{
    this.DestroyObstacle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got it working now. It moves offscreen completely now and thanks for pointing out my mistake on the transform.position line.